# Turning preorders into partial orders

Tags: notation, order-theory

Given a preorder $\preceq$ we can define a partial order $\leq$ as:

1. $x<y$ iff $x\preceq y$ and not $y\preceq x$
2. $x\leq y$ iff $x<y$ or $x=y$

Transitivity is inherited from $\preceq$, antisymmetry comes from (1) and reflexivity from (2).

My question: is there a name for this? If I just refer to "the partial order constructed from $\preceq$" will people understand what I mean?

Comment: @DanielRust You are right, I misunderstood the OP's intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the partial order constructed in this was the 'antisymmetric restriction' of the preorder. I imagine others might call it the maximal antisymmetric subrelation. I don't believe there's a standard notation or name for such a construction.